# Getting ERROR "fatal flex scanner internal error--end of buffer" missed, while handling CTRL+ C

Tags: c, shell, signals, flex-lexer

I am writing a small shell program, while trying to handle the <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> signal, I want trying to print a newline, when it is pressed.

Here's my code to do so.

```
static sigjmp_buf env;              

void sigint_handler(int signo){     
    siglongjmp(env, 42);            
}                                   


void myShellLoop(){                                                                  
    int parserStatus;                                                                

    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);                                                  

    while(1){                                                                        
        if(sigsetjmp(env,1)==42){                                                    
            printf("\n");                                                            
            continue;                                                                
        }                                                                            
        //Initialize a new command, to parse and execute.                            
        initializeGlobalCommand();                                                   

        parserStatus = yyparse();                                                    
        if(parserStatus == 0)                                                        
            executeShellCommand();                                                   
        else                                                                         
            printf("Not a valid shell command\n");                                   
    }                                                                                
}
```

But after I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, it does go to a newline, but then flex gives me this error:

```
fatal flex scanner internal error--end of buffer missed
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

How do I handle <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> properly?

Edit: Code snippet for `fork()`:

```
int execute(int cmdNumber){                                                                                                 
    pid_t pid;                                                                                                              
    int status;                                                                                                             

    pid = fork();                                                                                                           

    if(pid == 0){                                                                                                           
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);                                                                                            
        if(execvp(globalCommand.sCommands[cmdNumber].arguments[0], globalCommand.sCommands[cmdNumber].arguments) == -1){    
            perror("myShell: Command error");                                                                               
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                       
    else if(pid < 0){                                                                                                       
        //Error forking.                                                                                                    
        perror("myShell");                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                       
    else{                                                                                                                   
            do{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);                                                                                                                                                                             
            }while(!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status) && !globalCommand.background);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you 'brutaly' go out of the (f)lex(/yacc/bison) code to come back in *myShellLoop*, so it is not surprising that introduces inconsistency

Redefine `YY_INPUT` and when <kbd>control-c</kbd> is hit return a special character to return a special value/token managed in your parser to call *yyerror* to abort in a normal way

For instance in your lexer file :

```
%{
...
extern void my_yy_input(char*, int *, int);

#undef YY_INPUT
#define YY_INPUT(b,r,s) my_yy_input(b,&r,s)

%}
...
```

with

```
static sigjmp_buf env;              

void sigint_handler(int signo){     
  siglongjmp(env, '@');            
}                                   

void my_yy_input( char * buff, int * nRead, int maxToRead )
{
  *nRead =  1;

  if(sigsetjmp(env,1 ) == '@') {                                                    
    *buff = '@';
    return;
  }

  *buff = getchar();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, I was reading the flex docs trying to figure out YY_INPUT. 
So, from my understanding of the code above, when Ctrl-c is pressed, the buff will contain the symbol '@', this symbol I return to the parser, where I manage it to call yyerror. Am I right?

Comment: @HariOm yes, this is the idea, of course you can also return something else than '@' for the parser like a dedicated %token declared at the parser level. The goal is to not escape 'brutaly' from the lexer/parser but to stay in the normal behavior

Comment: The problem I am facing now is that I get segmentation fault after I press Ctrl-c, after a process has been forked. I have added my code for fork above.

Comment: @HariOm you only give partial pieces of code without link between them, difficult to help you in these conditions. If I well understand the parser is used to make a command filling _globalCommand_ then you execute it ? Did you check _globalCommand_ is filled in a good way ? What is the expected behavior of _control-c_, to abort all or to indicate the end of the command inputs ? May be you can open a new question for the fork problem because this seems to be an other problem ?

Comment: The thing is, when I call signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler) from myShellLoop(), Ctrl-c works just fine after a process is forked, I get no segmentation fault. But In the parent process, the problem is that, I am 'brutaly' exiting from lexer, like you said. If I implement signal(), in my flex file like you suggested, I still have to press enter after Ctrl-c, for it to get parsed. And I forgot to mention that the segmentation fault comes after forking and execvp(), so the command is getting executed properly,but when I interrupt with Ctrl-c, I get the seg fault error.

Comment: @HariOm it seems you need to catch the control-c only in the process using it, so to call _signal_ in only the parent or the child, if it is in the parent cancel it in the child or may be before to create the child

Comment: That's the thing, I am catching it only in the parent, but this is crashes the lexer.
I was wondering, when I am catching control-c from lexer, instead of returning it as token to the parser, can I just exit the lexer?

Comment: @HariOm I am lost, is the parsing done in the parent or the child process ?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. The parsing is done in the parent. Maybe I'll tackle this problem after sometime, with a clear head. Thanks for the suggestion and replying.